# How to filter Angular Mat Table on multiple column dropdowns

Tags: angular-material, mat-table

I am trying to filter angular mat table on dropdown values in each column header. I am able to filter on either any one of the dropdown value but not getting on multiple dropdown values. Is it possible on multiple dropdowns?. Here is what I have tried..

### HTML

```
          <table mat-table  [dataSource]="listData">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
             <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name
             <br>
               <mat-form-field>
               <select matNativeControl (change)="onChangeName($event.target.value)">
                 <option *ngFor="let name of names" [value]="name">
                   {{name | titlecase}}
                 </option>
                </select>
              </mat-form-field>
             </th>
             <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let rowIndex = index" >
             {{row.name}}
             </td>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="location ">
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Location
                <mat-form-field>
                    <select matNativeControl (change)="onChangeLocation($event.target.value)">
                      <option *ngFor="let location of locations" [value]="location">
                        {{track | titlecase}}
                    </option>
                    </select>
                  </mat-form-field>
             </th>
             <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let rowIndex = index" >
             {{row.location}}
             </td>
           </ng-container>
         </table>
```

### TS File

```
          ngOnInit(): void {
          this.listData=new MatTableDataSource(res);
          }

         onChangeName(name){
          this.selectedName=name;
          if(this.selectedLocation){
          this.listData.filter=name+this.selectedLocation;
          }
          else{
          this.listData.filter=name;
          }
         }

        onChangeLocation(location){
          this.selectedLocation=location;

         if(this.selectedName){
         this.listData.filter=location+this.selectedName;
         }
         else{
         this.listData.filter=location;
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit tricky, but hopefully I'll get you on the right track.
The way the default filter predicate works (simplified) is that  it checks whether any property of the passed data object (i.e. row) contains the passed filtered.

This won't work for you, so you override the [filterPredicate](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) of your DataSource. This still doesn't solve your issue fully though - the filter only accepts string objects, and preferably you will want to pass a custom "filter object". To go around it you can write your custom implementation of DataSource or serialize filter object before passing it as filter and then deserialize it in the filterPredicate.

A simple implementation would be (based on your example):

```
  private filter: any = {};

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(res);
    this.listData.filterPredicate = (data, filter): boolean => {
      const filterObject = JSON.parse(filter);

      for (const filterProperty in filterObject) {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(filterObject, filterProperty)) {
          continue;
        }

        const searchTerm: string = filterObject[filterProperty] ? filterObject[filterProperty].trim().toLowerCase() : '';
        const rowValue: string = data[filterProperty] ? data[filterProperty].trim().toLowerCase() : '';
        return rowValue.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
      }

      return true;
    };
  }

  onChangeName(name) {
    this.updateDataSourceFilter('name', name);
  }

  onChangeLocation(location) {
    this.updateDataSourceFilter('location', location);
  }


  private updateDataSourceFilter(propertyName: string, value: any): void {
    this.filter[propertyName] = value;

    this.listData.filter = JSON.stringify(this.filter);
  }
```

This is from top of my head, so it might not compile - but should give you basic idea of how you can implement this on your own.